# While sending attachment, activity API was not triggering using botframework-directlinejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, botframework

While sending attachment, activity API was not triggering. If i removed the attachments the API is triggering. How to fix this?

```
           directline
            .postActivity({
              type: "message",
              text: "Testing",
              attachments: [
                {
                  contentType: "image/png",
                  contentUrl: attachment.uploadedFiles[0],
                },
              ],
              value: {
                eventType: "customEvent",
                eventProperties: {
                  conversation_id:""
                  user_id: ""
                },
              },
              from: {
                id: "",
                name: "",
                role: "agent",
              },
            })
```